# Moving blocks in a Trackmania Nations Forever's track

Tags: game

I'm looking for a program that can move one or ideally all blocks of a map in Trackmania Nations Forever. The move would simply be a shift on the X or Y axis.  If possible, free and works on Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate.

Comment: If anyone has any idea

Comment: please add an answer.

Comment: I haven't found anything so far.